# Laravel Custom Validation for Table

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

[table 'angkatan'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqO57.png)

I have table named 'angkatan' which has id, id_angkatan, nama_angkatan, and status. status column is enum contain 'aktif' and 'tidak aktif'.
I want to give rules for this table in Laravel with validation where this table only allowed to have a maximum of 4 and a minimum of 1 of status 'aktif'. no rules for how many statuses 'tidak aktif'

---

```
$jml_angkatan_aktif = \App\Models\Angkatan::where('status', 'Aktif')->get('id_angkatan')->count();
```

With the $jml_angkatan_aktif variable I get the amount of id_angkatan which has 'Aktif' so I can count whether it is beyond 4 and under 1. but the problem is I can't give this custom validation. the purpose of this custom validation is I want people can't add 'angkatan' if there are already 4 status 'aktif' in this table. I hope you can understand my explanation. here is the code from AngkatanController in-store method.

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
        'id_angkatan' => 'required|unique:angkatan',
        'nama_angkatan' => 'required|unique:angkatan',
        'status' => ['required', function ($attribute, $e) { 
            $jml_angkatan_aktif = \App\Models\Angkatan::where('status', 'Aktif')->get('id_angkatan')->count();
            if ($jml_angkatan_aktif > 4) {
                $e('Batas Maksimal '.$attribute.' Aktif untuk Angkatan adalah 4');
            }
            elseif ($jml_angkatan_aktif < 1) {
                $e('Batas Minimal '.$attribute.' Aktif untuk Angkatan adalah 1');
            }
        },
    ],
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json(['status'=>0, 'error'=>$validator->errors()->toArray()]);
    } else {
        $angkatan = new Angkatan;
        $angkatan->id_angkatan = $request->id_angkatan;
        $angkatan->nama_angkatan = $request->nama_angkatan;
        $angkatan->status = $request->status;
        
        $query = $angkatan->save();
        if ($query) {
            return response()->json(['status'=>1, 'msg'=>'Angkatan Berhasil Ditambah']);
        }
    }        
}
```

here is the page view list of 'angkatan'
[view of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncpm9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally got the result what i wanted, using nested if solved the problem, here is the final code

```
public function edit(Request $request, $id)
{
    $angkatan_aktif = \App\Models\Angkatan::where('status', 'Aktif')->get();

    $angkatan = Angkatan::find($id);
    $angkatan->id_angkatan = $request->id_angkatan;
    $angkatan->status = $request->status;
    $angkatan->nama_angkatan = $request->nama_angkatan;
    $angkatan->status = $request->status;

    if($angkatan_aktif->count() == 4){

        if($angkatan->status == "Aktif"){

            return redirect('/pengaturan')->with('pesan-angkatan-error', 'Gagal edit! Angkatan Aktif Sudah Mencapai Batas Maksimum : 4');
        
        }
        
        elseif($angkatan->status == "Tidak Aktif"){

            $query = $angkatan->save();
            if ($query){
                return redirect('/pengaturan')->with('pesan-angkatan', 'Angkatan Berhasil Diedit');
            }

        }
    }
    elseif($angkatan_aktif->count() < 4){

        $query = $angkatan->save();
        if ($query){
            return redirect('/pengaturan')->with('pesan-angkatan', 'Angkatan Berhasil Diedit');
        }
    }
}
```

and here is the result, with blade conditional the add button will not appears, so it will not bother me to use store method, now i cant add 'angkatan' anymore if status 'aktif' = 4 nor have status 'aktif' more than 4 through update method as i wanted.

[if status 'aktif' < 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uk2g9.png)

---

[if status 'aktif' = 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Azinx.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#custom-validation-rules) laravel documentation for creating custom rules?

Seems like you missed $value argue in your closure:

```
'status' => ['required', function ($attribute, $value, $e) { 
        $jml_angkatan_aktif = \App\Models\Angkatan::where('status', 'Aktif')->get('id_angkatan')->count();
        if ($jml_angkatan_aktif > 4) {
            $e('Batas Maksimal '.$attribute.' Aktif untuk Angkatan adalah 4');
        }
        elseif ($jml_angkatan_aktif < 1){
            $e('Batas Minimal '.$attribute.' Aktif untuk Angkatan adalah 1');
        }
    },
```